# Which path to follow to implement oculus rift DK2 connection with my threeJS application

Tags: three.js, webgl, oculus, virtual-reality, webvr

I will go straight to my problem. So, I 've got :

1. an Oculus Rift DK2
2. Win8 + AMD Radeon HD 7500
3. A webGL/threeJS web application

and I want to use my rift with the application (not only watching, but also tracking).

**My question which path should I follow to do this?**

After my research, I have seen some suggestions on this issue :

**1.** Downloading a specific branch of Chromium and enabling the new experimetnal webVR API.

**2.** Use a plug-in so I don't have to download and install chromium (a plugin like this : https://github.com/borismus/webvr-boilerplate , https://github.com/borismus/webvr-polyfill)

**3.** Wait for the webVR to be a standard (don't want that!)

In simple words, there are 2 options : either I go with chromium or I do it on chrome with a plugin that acts like the webVR API (I am not sure if I am describing that right).

For those that had the same problem, what was your approach? Should I go with chromium or with the other strategy? Why?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why you're getting downvoted, you misunderstood a few things but you shouldn't be penalized for that IMO.

Comment: @brianpeiris I just want some ideas, directions and advice on this issue. I am sure I might have misunderstood some things and if someone is able to explain them to me I 'd be gratefull.

Answer (score 4):

The after the recent release of the 1.0 WebVR APIs, the various helper scripts, libraries and polyfills are still in a state of flux. Nevertheless, I'll try to answer your questions:

1. Yes, you should to download the latest Chromium WebVR build. It implements the new 1.0 WebVR spec. You should *also* download Firefox Nightly. Nightly's WebVR implementation has not been updated to the 1.0 spec but it is still usable. Those are the only two options you have for accessing the WebVR APIs on PCs.
2. You should *also* consider using webvr-boilerplate, webvr-polyfill.

   webvr-boilerplate and webvr-polyfill are not plugins (that is a specific term used to refer to third-party components which are installed in browsers. E.g. Firefox has a Flash plugin).

   **webvr-polyfill** is a JavaScript helper library that you simply need to include in your app (as opposed to a plugins which need to be installed in the browser itself). It will fill-in the WebVR API if a particular browser doesn't support it. E.g. if you're using a browser on an Android or iOS device, it will fill in the APIs so that the browser will function as a Google Cardboard device using the phone's accelerometer/gyroscope sensors and applying the appropriate lens distortion.

   If you're on a desktop PC without an HMD, it will fill in the APIs so that you can use your mouse and keyboard to move the camera and display your app in a monocular view without distortion. The latest (unreleased) version of webvr-polyfill will even take care of filling the gap between the old and new versions of the WebVR API, so if you're using Firefox Nightly, you only have to worry about the 1.0 version of the WebVR APIs in your app.

   **webvr-boilerplate** is a library that takes care of the typical logic and UI that you'd have to build into a WebVR app. It uses webvr-polyfill and it adds UI for entering and exiting VR or fullscreen mode and takes care of some of quirks of mobile browsers. This way, all you have to worry about is Three.js and your app code.
3. webvr-boilerplate and webvr-polyfill work together so that you don't have to wait for the WebVR 1.0 APIs. On mobile devices, you can use stable versions of browsers (although the dev versions of mobile browsers will give you a better VR experience). On desktop, you have to use either the Chromium WebVR builds or Firefox Nightly to use WebVR.